# Match delimeter(|) separated values field in mysql select query

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-like

In my mysql table one of the field has values like (1|2|3) stored in it.

```
  id   Skills
 ----  --------
   1   1|2|3|5
   2     2|4|5
   3    4|6|3
   4    5|2|3|1
```

I want to search and list the id's based on the skills matched. If i want to list the id's of the skill which contains `3`, i have to list the ids `1,3,4`. Like if i want to list the id's of the skill which contains `1,5 (either 1 nor 5 or both)`(like mulitple values 1,4,3) then i want to list `1,2,4(i want to list 2 also`). Any help could be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"Any help could be greatly appreciated."_ - Great, here goes: pick up a book on normalization. You need a `Person_Skills` junction table, where you link `PersonID` and `SkillID` on each row. Delimited values in a single column is just a disaster waiting to happen. What if you want to remove skill 5 for all people, or want to find all people with skill 2 but not skill 3, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
select id
from your_table
where find_in_set('3', replace(skills, '|',',') > 0

select id
from your_table
where find_in_set('3', replace(skills, '|',',')) > 0
or find_in_set('5', replace(skills, '|',',')) > 0
```

But you should actually change your DB structure. Always store single values in a column to avoid such problems!

Comment: have you tried this? `mysql> select FIND_IN_SET('3', '1|3');` it works only with comma-separated strings

Comment: Manual states: _"A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters"_. I see you now do a `replace()` but that will hurt performance as it will do a full table scan.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Didn't notice the `|`

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE Skills REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]' = 1
OR Skills REGEXP '[[:<:]]5[[:>:]]' = 1
```

Comment: thank you. Will that REGEXP [[:<:]] also match other delimeters.

Comment: This regex is to match whole word. That is if you have 1|2|3 then 1,2 and 3 are whole word

Comment: You can also try `find_in_set` solution with replace, I think that isbetter solution to this.

Comment: i have tried both find in set and the REGEXP, both worked, thank you.